# Adding 'isLoading' variable to $resource service (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, http, service, resources, loading

I have a Service which uses $resource to pull in API data. I want to included a isLoaded variable to define whether the API response has executed.

My service currently looks like this:

```
    app.factory('PlayerService', ['$resource', function($resource) {

      return $resource(
        'http://api/endpoint', {player_id: "@player_id"}
      )

}]);
```

I want to add functionality something like this (pseudocode)...

```
    app.factory('PlayerService', ['$resource', function($resource) {

      $scope.isLoaded = false;

      return $resource(
        'http://api/endpoint', {player_id: "@player_id"}
      )

      $scope.isLoaded = "true";

}]);
```

...but I'm struggling with the syntax. Do I need to write a separate function? Does this logic need to be contained in the controller as opposed to the service?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add a isLoaded variable.

There is a $resolved method in $resourse service which does what you're trying to do. See documentation on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource :

> $resolved: true after first server interaction is completed (either
>   with success or rejection), false before that. Knowing if the Resource
>   has been resolved is useful in data-binding.

example :

```
var test = $resource('http://api/endpoint', {player_id: "@player_id"});
test.get(function(result) {
    console.log(result.$resolved);
});
```

The result.$resolved will be true after the data is loaded. It will remain false if the data didn't load.

Comment: That looks like just what I'm after, but the documentation is very thin. How do you implement it? Would you include it in the service if this is where $resource is invoked?

Comment: I edited my answer with an example. The $resolved is invoked on the promise (result) from the $resource call (see example). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is alternative way to use loader for your app:

Use this feature of angular : **$http.pendingRequests**

My controller:

```
$rootScope.loaderExceptionCount = 0 ;
    $scope.isAnythingLoading = function() {
        console.log($http.pendingRequests, $http);
        return $http.pendingRequests.length > $rootScope.loaderExceptionCount;
    };
```

Here is your HTML code, where isAnythingLoading() is getting called:

```
<div ng-show="isAnythingLoading()" class="pageLoader">
        <div class="loaderBackdrop"></div>
            <div class="sk-wave">
                    <div class="sk-rect sk-rect1"></div>
                    <div class="sk-rect sk-rect2"></div>
                    <div class="sk-rect sk-rect3"></div>
                    <div class="sk-rect sk-rect4"></div>
                    <div class="sk-rect sk-rect5"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div ui-view=""></div>
```